# Recursive function - countdown

Tags: python, recursion

I am learning python, the following is an example of a recursive function on the textbook:

```
def countdown(n):
    if n<= 0:
        print('Blastoff!')
    else:
        print:(n)
        countdown(n-1)
```

it supposed to display a countdown but I'm not getting any output on my visual studio, please help!

Comment: `print:(n)` is not valid syntax. Also, you didn't call the function.

Comment: Sure its valid syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you call your function, also `print:(n)` should not have the colon.

```
def countdown(n):
    if n<= 0:
        print('Blastoff!')
    else:
        print(n)
        countdown(n-1)

countdown(10)
```